# Most accurate way to cut up a shape at 45 degrees

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, slices

I am working with the latest version of Adobe Illustrator. I have the following:

[image: two rounded rectangles]

I would like to cup the shape at the following location, so that I create a flat document icon that is folded in one corner:

[image: slice line of rounded rectangle]

How I can achieve this? The knife tool doesn't do straight lines! Even though I press Ctrl / Shift / Alt .. etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: I usually create a shape and use pathfinder panel to cut out some part.

Comment: Knowing what I'm trying to achieve, can you please walk me through what shape .. etc you'd create? And how you'd cut them using pathfinder panel?

Comment: Take the pen/line tool and draw that line. Then in pathfinder use divide and delete the other part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I worked in Outline mode (Ctrl+Y).

1. You have you shapes stacked.
   [image]
2. Turn on Smart Guides (Ctrl+U) it will help to fit exactly into intersection points. Do a straight line of cut with Pen tool (P).
   [image]
3. Do and complete any shape which will enclose your smaller rectangle
   [image]
4. Select all shapes, open Pathfinder panel and use Trim.
   [image]
5. Select unnecessary shapes with Direct Select (A), you can select even part of path or one point. And press Delete. At first press you will delete exactly what selected. After delete the whole path will be selected - press Delete second time.
   [image]
6. Back to Normal mode (Ctrl+Y).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click TRIM or MERGE in the pathfinder, then use the Direct selection tool and delete all unneeded anchor points!
[image]

Comment: Better not to keep opened paths.

Comment: @Vnovak Better in what way?

Comment: Opened path can be a cause of error (e.g. with some RIPs)

Comment: @Vnovak OK. Mathematically the fill is calculated as if it is closed. I have never seen problems with that. You can easily close the path by Ctrl+J but I think it's just an extra unnecessary step in this case. :)

Comment: Mathematically, stray points also must not raise errors :)

Comment: @Vnovak Can you explain how to trigger this error that you talk about?!

Comment: Push file to RIP and see results.

Comment: @Vnovak What do you mean by "push file to RIP"?

Comment: @Komental just close the gap and keep Vnovak happy ;)